# What's calling CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, stack-trace, core-foundation

I'm rather confused by this stack trace (only the confusing part is shown):

```
-[NSXMLDocument length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10187e010
An uncaught exception was raised
-[NSXMLDocument length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10187e010
(
   0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f5d6286 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9213bd5e objc_exception_throw + 43
   2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f6624ce -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 190
   3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f5c3133 ___forwarding___ + 371
   4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f5c2f48 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
   5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f548c66 CFDataGetLength + 118
   6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8f5791df CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation + 31
   7   asLJ                                0x0000000100013828 +[stripHTML stripAllHtmlFromString:] + 212
```

In particular, I don't understand where the call to `CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation` is happening, so I don't know what part of my code (`+[stripHTML stripAllHtmlFromString:]`) is causing the exception.  What's causing the call to `CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation`?  If it's obvious, what is it that I'm doing wrong that's causing the exception?  In the future, how can I go about determining what's calling `CFStringCreateFromExternalRepresentation`?

Here's `+[stripHTML stripAllHtmlFromString:]`:

```
+ (NSString *)stripAllHtmlFromString:(NSString *)inputString
{
    // based on code from http://sugarmaplesoftware.com/25/strip-html-tags/#comment-71

    NSError *theError = NULL;
    NSString *modifiedInputString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",inputString]; // adding some spare newlines at the end to ensure that things will work even with a short non-HTML string
    NSXMLDocument *theDocument = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:modifiedInputString
                                                                  options:NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML
                                                                    error:&theError];

    NSString *theXSLTString = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"
                                "<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' xmlns:xhtml='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>"
                                "<xsl:output method='text'/>"
                                "<xsl:template match='xhtml:head'></xsl:template>"
                                "<xsl:template match='xhtml:script'></xsl:template>"
                                "</xsl:stylesheet>";    
    NSData *theData = [theDocument objectByApplyingXSLTString:theXSLTString arguments:NULL error:&theError];
    [theDocument release];
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Is this something you can reproduce? If so, reproduce it with a debug build of your app, running under the debugger, set to break on exceptions. That will show the precise line in your code that's responsible and may also show more specifics in the backtrace.

Comment: @KenThomases: Er, actually, I have been able to reproduce it now, by feeding in an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, actually, probably `-objectByApplyingXSLTString:arguments:error:` returned an `NSXMLDocument` and not an `NSData`. So, the call to `-[NSString initWithData:encoding:]` is invoking `-length` on what it thinks is an `NSData`, but `NSXMLDocument` doesn't recognize that.

Comment: If I understand the `-objectByApplyingXSLTString:arguments:error:` documentation correctly, it should return `NSData` when the output should be plain text or RTF, `NSXMLDocument` otherwise, and my XSLT asks for text output, so I guess either something's broken with my XSLT under certain circumstances or there's some kind of very narrow bug with `-objectByApplyingXSLTString:arguments:error:` (probably more likely my XSLT)?

Answer (score 0):

[Ken Thomases's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669759/291280) seems to have it exactly right—for some reason, for very short input (particularly the empty string), `-objectByApplyingXSLTString:arguments:error:` with the given XSLT returns an `NSXMLDocument` (even though I don't think it should).  To fix it, I first detect whether we got an `NSXMLDocument` and if so, turn it into a string representation of the XML and feed that back into the method; otherwise assume we got the `NSData` that we'd originally expected.

Replacing the last 3 lines of the given method (from `NSData *theData =`... on) with the code below seems to have fixed the issue.

```
// Had a report of an exception that seemed to indicate objectByApplyingXSLTString:arguments:error: was returning an NSXMLDocument objectinstead of an NSData object, so let's guard against that.  (discussed at https://stackoverflow.com/q/10669479/291280 )
NSObject *XSTLresult = [theDocument objectByApplyingXSLTString:theXSLTString arguments:NULL error:&theError];
[theDocument release];
if ([XSTLresult isKindOfClass:[NSXMLDocument class]]) {
    // If the result is an NSXMLDocument, call XMLData to get an NSData object, turn it into a string, and feed that back into this method...
    return [self stripAllHtmlFromString:[[[NSString alloc]
                                          initWithData:[(NSXMLDocument *)XSTLresult XMLData]
                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                         autorelease]
            ];
} else {
    // Otherwise, assume we have an NSData object.
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)XSTLresult encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Why not check `if ([XSTLresult isKindOfClass:[NSXMLDocument class]])`? It would be a little more straightforward.

Comment: @KurtRevis: er... almost certainly because I've been programming in Python a lot more than Objective-C and was thinking duck-typing.  I agree that `isKindOfClass:` is more straightforward. *edited into the answer*